# How can I display the number of questions for each category in each level?

Tags: php, html

I have one table named questions with fields: id,cat_name,question,level

There are six categories and three levels( easy, middle,difficult).

How can I display the number of questions for each category in each level?

```
<table id=""class="table table-striped table-hover">
<thead >
<tr class="table-active table-dark">
<th scope="row" >Cat Name</th>
<th>Total questions</th>
<th>easy</th>
<th>middle</th>
<th>difficult</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

foreach($con->query('SELECT
  level, cat, COUNT(*)
FROM
  questions
GROUP BY
  level, cat') as $row)
  { 
echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>" . $row['cat'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(*)'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['level'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>"; 

}

?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now the results appear duplicate in the table.
Any help?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you're pretty close to a solution. I wouldn't put the query itself inside the `foreach ()` loop like that. Just put it in front like this:

```
$rows = <query>
if (isset($rows)) {
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        <process a row>
    }
}
```

In the query itself you use `cat`, whereas you say your table contains `cat_name`. One of these is wrong.

Finally, to use a `COUNT()` in a query you can use `AS`, like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT
          cat_name, 
          level, 
          COUNT(*) AS question_count
        FROM
          questions
        GROUP BY
          level, 
          cat_name';
$rows = $con->query($sql);
if (isset($rows)) {
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cat_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['level'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['question_count'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }
} else {
    echo "<tr><td colspan="3">No data</td></tr>";
}
```

Now for the restructuring of the data so that you can show all the levels on one row:

```
$sql = 'SELECT
          cat_name, 
          level, 
          COUNT(*) AS question_count
        FROM
          questions
        GROUP BY
          level, 
          cat_name';
$dataRows = $con->query($sql);
if (isset($dataRows )) {
    $tableRows = [];
    foreach ($dataRows as $dataRow) {
        $catagory = $dataRow['cat_name'];
        $level    = $dataRow['level'];
        $count    = $dataRow['question_count'];
        $tableRows[$catagory][$level] = $count;
    }
    foreach ($tableRows as $catagory => $tableRow) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . ($tableRow['difficult'] ?? 0) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . ($tableRow['middle'] ?? 0) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . ($tableRow['easy'] ?? 0) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . array_sum($tableRow ?? [0]) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $catagory . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }
} else {
    echo "<tr><td colspan="3">No data</td></tr>";
}
```

The problem I have here is that I don't know what your levels are called. I've used 'difficult', 'middle' and 'easy', as in your table, but that might not be correct.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem still. I will explain more with pictures :

I want to show under each level the number of questions
Please see the picture:
https://ibb.co/jb76XFB

Comment: @rcweb OK, got it. This requires restructuring of the data. Let me give that a try.

Comment: @rcweb I edited my answer. I'm missing information, so I cannot be sure this will work. It most likely won't.

Comment: Excellent, great job, works as it should, thank you very much.

Comment: There is only a small error appearing at the top of the page :
Notice: Undefined index: middle in.
Repeat with words : easy middle difficult  but the code is work fine.

Comment: @rcweb Sorry, I have no idea where that notice comes from.

Comment: No problem I solved the error by add : $tableRow['easy']  = ""; with other words after foreach loop. Thanks again

Comment: KIKO , i cant fix this err when i set $tableRow['difficult'] to = "" the err not show but the count not work for level.
see the photo:
https://ibb.co/djY0bwt
I think the problem is that variables must be defined before they are used.
any idea ?

Comment: @rcweb: Yes, array indexes have to exist before they can be used. What you can do is: `echo "<td>" . ($tableRow['difficult'] ?? 0) . "</td>"`, and the same for the other cases. See: [Null Coalescing Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce).